# asp.net request.filter override stream.read

Tags: asp.net, filter, httprequest

I want to change request content, that is, I want convert Chinese traditional to Chinese simplified, they are **1:1** mapping. I use the following code:

Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Request.Filter = new RequestFilter(Request.Filter);
}
```

The usage of HttpRequest.filter is here: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.filter.aspx)

RequestFilter:

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    // the length of buffer is 8192, will truncate my request stream 
    int len = _sink.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    if (len == 0)
    {
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, count);
        return len;
    }


    System.Text.Encoding curEncoding = HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentEncoding;
    string strBuffer = curEncoding.GetString(buffer);

    Regex regQuery = new Regex(@"=([^&]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    strBuffer = regQuery.Replace(strBuffer, new MatchEvaluator((match) =>
    {
        string val = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(match.Groups[1].ToString());

        return "=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(ChineseConverter.Convert(val, 
            ChineseConversionDirection.TraditionalToSimplified));
    }));

    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, count);
    byte[] newBuff = curEncoding.GetBytes(strBuffer);
    newBuff.CopyTo(buffer, 0);

    return len;
}
```

I override the method **Read** on **Stream** class, but the first parameter **byte[] buffer** which default length is 8192 and will truncate my content.

> eg: encodeURI('中') is '%E4%B8%AD', may be only '%E4' at the end of **byte[] buffer**

How can I get all content in first parameter byte[] buffer, or could anyone tell me some tips to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you want to modify the length of the data inside a request (or response) using a Filter you will need to use a buffered technique.  I've posted a sample project which demonstrates this buffered filtering technique using an HttpModule.

https://github.com/snives/HttpModuleRewrite